# How can I change the endpoint address programmatically in the client site?

Tags: wcf

How can I change the endpoint address programmatically in the client site?

Answer (score 8):

```
proxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://newaddress");
```

where `proxy` is an instance of the client class generated when importing the WSDL. Or you can specify the address when creating the client proxy:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://newaddress");
var proxy = new SomeClientProxy("BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorld", endpoint);
```

Comment: you actually **cannot** change the endpoint after the proxy has been created - you must do this before calling the first method on your proxy.

Comment: Good point @marc_s. Does this mean that the first example I gave won't work or it will work only if done before calling the first method?

Comment: @Darin: I think it'll throw an exception if you try to do it after a method on the service has already been called (not 100% sure though). Best practise is to always do these setup things first before any calls :-)

Comment: Help.  If I don't change anything my call to the service works.  If I change the URL (using code similar to above) I get a SecurityNegotiationException. I even set the URL to the same value that it is before the call (in effect, changing nothing).

Answer (score -1):

http://deadkota.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/wcf-client-change-endpoint-address-dynamically/

```
using(abcServiceClient proxy = new ABCServiceClient())
{
    proxy.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8082/ABCService");
    proxy.Open();
    proxy.Function();
}
```