# Specify IP address of WCF endpoint at runtime

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a bunch of remote machines all running the same WCF service over HTTP.  I have a central configuration utility that needs to decide at runtime which of these to connect to.  I do not want to define all the endpoints in the configuration file because this is all database driven.

I naively tried this:

```
CustomerServiceClient GetClientForIPAddress(string ipAddress)
{
 string address = String.Format("http://{0}/customerservice.svc", ipAddress);
 var client = new CustomerServiceClient("?", address);
 return client; 
}
```

where CustomerServiceClient is my service reference proxy class, but (unsurprisingly) it gave me the following error:

> Could not find endpoint element with
>   name '?' and contract
>   'SkyWalkerCustomerService.ICustomerService'
>   in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because
>   no endpoint element matching this name
>   could be found in the client element.

So how do I declare an endpoint at runtime and point my service reference to it?

.NET 3.5

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978962/how-to-change-endpoint-address-programatically-in-the-client-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a piece of code i use to configure my endpoints in a silverlight app:

```
    private void initEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endPoint, string serviceName)
    {
        Uri hostUri = Application.Current.Host.Source;
        string vdir = hostUri.LocalPath.Substring(0, hostUri.LocalPath.IndexOf("/ClientBin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        string wcfBaseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}/WebServices/", hostUri.Scheme, hostUri.Host, hostUri.Port, vdir);

        endPoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(wcfBaseUri + serviceName));
    }
```

The *endPoint* passed in is the endpoint to be configured, and *serviceName* is the name of a service, like *MyLoggingService.svc*. All i do is point it at a new address (in this case a known location within the hosting website). Use this as a sample, and just pass in your own string addresses from where-ever.

It is called with a bit of code that looks like this:

```
_loggingService = new LoggingServiceClient();
initEndpoint(_loggingService.Endpoint, "LoggingService.svc");
```

Hope this helps. Take it and run with it, chop it up and make it your own :)