# How can I dynamically set a .Net 3.5 Web Service that uses SSL?

Tags: c#, .net, webservice-client, service-model

I'm writing an application that needs to connect to a web service.  Under certain circumstances, I need to toggle the endpoint address.

I assume this is as simple as changing the `System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint`, when the address needs to change.  However, I'm getting an exception when I do this because one addresses requires SSL, and the other address doesn't.

How can I *correctly* update web services endpoint address?

Note: This is a C#, .Net 3.5 project.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978962/how-can-i-change-the-endpoint-address-programmatically-in-the-client-site

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but where does the proxy come from?

Comment: Give this a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx.

Comment: Are you connecting to a wcf service or an xml web service?

Comment: It's XML, but it's an old ASP.net form of web service.

Comment: Then give this a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx and change the Url property of the proxy created when you add the web reference.

Comment: I think the proxy approach is the correct way to solve this.  I just need to figure out a way to do it.  In the "olden days" you could just update a `Url` property on your web service class.  Looks like it doesn't work that way any more.  I'll try to figure this one out on my own, unless someone is aware of a simpler answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.  When Visual Studio generates the wrapper classes for your service, the `[ServiceName]SoapClient` has a constructor that takes a binding and an endpoint as a parameter.  Define these and just pass them to the constructor.

Here is a pseudo-example.

```
    void InitializeMyWebService(bool useSSLSite)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding b = useSSLSite ? 
            new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport) : 
            new BasicHttpBinding();

        EndpointAddress e = useSSLSite ? 
            new EndpointAddress("https://www.example.com/svc/MyWebService.asmx") :
            new EndpointAddress("http://intranet_server/svc/MyWebService.asmx");

        myWebService = new MyWebServiceSoapClient(b, e);
    }
}
```

`MyWebService` will now work, as defined by the `userSSLSite` parameter to our method.