# Using an IP address for a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# app that calls my WCF on my server.

At some time I will want to move part of my uploading process from client to server to a different server.

So, this is what I was going to do.

My desktop application invokes a WCF hosted on my server using the full DNS name ~ www.mysite.com.

That [web method] will then return an IP address to the client.

The client will then upload images to a DIFFERENT server that is accessible only by an IP address.

The idea is that if my app is successful and I would need to 'load-balance' the image uploads I would then have a mechanism to specify different destination servers to my clients.

So, I started looking in StackOverFlow for a way to dynamically set the IP address/End-Point of my WCF.  This was easy to do for web services but it seems to me a bit more difficult for WCF.

Needless to say I was about to go through the answers here but came across a comment saying that the WCF needs to be using DNS.

Is this true?

As this is the only server I got and it is using DNS (I have not got access to a secondary server yet) I cannot test this out.

Are both things possible?

Comment: `[WebMethod]` is an ASMX web service, not WCF .....

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking if the client can be pointed to a different IP address dynamically, or are you asking if you can dynamically assign as IP address for the services identity? If it's just the client, can you not just do `client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("my.ip.addr.ess");`

Comment: @LaMMMy  Thanks for replying. Yes, that was what I meant. Sorry for for my wording...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a web service client, you can change the server endpoint programmatically. It has nothing to do with using WCF or not in the server.

```
MyClient client = new MyService.MyClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("target URL"));
client.Open();
```

You could find more details on the [EndPointAddress MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope I helped!

Comment: Did this work? I did some experimentation and found that the `client.Endpoint.Address` could not be altered, even though it would allow the operation, when tracing the endpoint being called was still the original. Not until I instantiated an entirely new client would it change ala: `client = new MyService.MyClient("my.endpoint.address");`

Comment: See this thread as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978962/how-can-i-change-the-endpoint-address-programmatically-in-the-client-site
 I believe the reason is, once WCF makes that initial client association the client state is maintained, so changing the the address in the WCF client, does not actually change it at the Web Request layer.

Comment: @LaMMMy Oh dear. This may not be workable then. I have not tested it yet though. thanks for the link

Comment: In case anyone thinks this is the answer I have found this does not work.  I have already awarded the answer but I should have tested 1st.  I am a bit of an idiot.

Comment: @Andrew I suppose I could delete the answer. But preferably you could edit it and make it right, or explain what is wrong...

Comment: Hi,   thanks for commenting. I get an SPN error. I cannot find a solution to this.  You would think if you can declare the endpoint as you did that it would work. This is not ur fault but mine, I am happy for you to retain the 'green tick' :)

Comment: As you probably understand, nobody actually cares for the stackoverflow score. It is just very important for users navigating to your question to be able to identify if an answer is useful or not. Anyway, I suppose that in the scope of the initial question, the answer was indeed helpful and therefore I will leave it as it is. Regarding the [SPN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677949(v=vs.85).aspx) problem, I suppose you coule ask another question with some details... Good luck :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I do have another question/approcah. It seems the answer is to use channels.  But I am stuck. Question to follow :)

Answer (score -1):

```
MyClient client = new MyService.MyClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("target URL"));
client.Open();
```

It works, we could also use

```
myService.MyClient client = new myService.MyClient ();
 //enter code here, when the service is created as wcf application
```

Comment: _"we could also use"_ - yes, we could, but what does that do? How does this differ from the accepted answer?